# how to use order_by in two field and given the same priority to them

Tags: django

I have model and i wont to sort my objects based two fields and  two fields have the same priority

```
class Item(models.Model): 

    rank1 = models.IntegerField()
    rank2 = models.IntegerField()
```

how to sort and tow field have same priority

```
Item.objects.order_by(???)  # rank1 + rank2
```

example
i need to see this sort after use order by :
rank1 : 10
rank2 : 8
rank1 : 7
rank2 : 6

Comment: If RG_RG's answer has solved your problem, please mark your question as answered, but I don't see how you can achieve the output you show in your example if the fields `rank1` and `rank2` are attributes of the same row in the database table. The only way I can see to get the output you want is to `union` the  table with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to sum 2 columns and use the results to sort them.

```
Item.objects.extra(select={'fieldsum':'rank1 + rank2'}, order_by=('-fieldsum',) )
```

Or, you can use [F() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import F

Item.objects.annotate(fieldsum=F('rank1') + F('rank2')).order_by('-fieldsum')
```

Comment: thank you so much , i will check today (: